# Use index vector to select / remove values from a list

Tags: r, list

This is a question that came up in my mind when seeing that [SO QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447142/how-can-i-remove-shared-values-from-a-list-of-vectors)

```
x <- list(c(1:6,32,24), c(1:4,8,10,12,13,17,24), c(1:5,9:15,17,18,19,20,32))

IND <- !duplicated(unlist(x))
```

#### INPUT

> ```
> > x
> [[1]]
> [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6 32 24
>
> [[2]]
>  [1]  1  2  3  4  8 10 12 13 17 24
>
> [[3]]
>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 17 18 19 20 32
> ```

```
> IND
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[23] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Is it possible to access the list elements with IND so I get:

#### DESIRED OUTPUT

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6 32 24
>
> [[2]]
> [1]  8 10 12 13 17
>
> [[3]]
> [1]  9 11 14 15 18 19 20
> ```

Normally I would access the elements like `x[[1]][1]` etc ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
IND2 <-split(IND, rep(1:3, sapply(x, length)))
Map(function(x, y) x[y], x, IND2)
[[1]]
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6 32 24

[[2]]
[1]  8 10 12 13 17

[[3]]
[1]  9 11 14 15 18 19 20
```

The idea is to transform the `IND` vector back to a list using the corresponding lengths. Then using Map to loop through each list element for subsetting.

Or try a reshape2 & tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
melt(x) %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(value)) %>% 
  with(., split(value, L1))
```

Comment: Did you use Map instead of mapply to ensure the outcome stays a list?

Comment: No, it's just a personal thing. As Map is a simple wrapper to mapply you can use both.